Will abandoned I-539 request affect original visa?
I initiated an I-539 change of status from F1 to B2 request this May. My F1 grace period ended on May and I stayed two more month in the US while the request is pending, which should not be a problem according to my knowledge.
The question is, when I left United States as I-539 request is still pending, I received the notice from USCIS saying my request was denied because I left the USA. Is my F1 Visa still valid now as the expiration date on the passport has not been passed? Because if it is still valid I could use a new I-20 to reenter the USA.

Your visa was not voided by INA 222(g). INA 222(g) is not triggered if you left the US while a timely-filed, non-frivolous Extension of Stay or Change of Status application was pending. See 9 FAM 302.1-9(B)(1).c(4)(b):

[...] In addition, if an applicant departs after the date on the Form
I-94 passes, but before their application for extension or change of
status has been decided by USCIS, they must be subject to a blanket
exemption from INA 222(g), if the application was filed in a "timely
manner" and is "nonfrivolous" in nature. [...]

Furthermore, even if you hadn't applied for Change of Status, your visa would still not have been voided by INA 222(g), because that normally happens if you stay past the date on your I-94. But as an F1 student, you were admitted with "D/S" on your I-94, not a date. So you do not trigger INA 222(g) no matter how long you stay past the end of your program, unless while in the US, you applied to USCIS for a benefit and were denied for being out of status, or you were put into removal proceedings and a judge ruled you to be out of status. See 9 FAM 302.1-9(B)(1).c(3):

[...] An applicant who has been admitted to the United States for
"duration of status" is ineligible under INA 222(g) only if:
(a)  (U) USCIS finds a status violation while adjudicating a request
for an immigration benefit; or
(b)  (U) An IJ finds a status violation in proceedings against the
applicant.  In determining whether INA 222(g) applies, your assessment
of whether the applicant did or did not maintain lawful status is
irrelevant.

So your F1 visa is still valid if unexpired and you are otherwise eligible to use it to enter. Of course, the immigration officer at entry has the discretion to deny you entry even if you have a valid visa.
